# CasperJs not capturing screenshot for some sites

Tags: extjs, phantomjs, casperjs

I have written some test case using CasperJS.

```
var baseUrl = "http://cng20018241:9090";
var require = patchRequire(require);

casper.options.viewportSize = {
  width: 1024,
  height: 800
}


casper.test.begin('Connecting to site', function suite(test) {
  casper.start(baseUrl, function() {
    this.wait(5000, function() {
        this.echo("I've waited for 5 seconds.");
    });
  })
  .then(function(){
    this.captureSelector('c:\\temp\\screenshot.png', 'html')}
)
  .run(function() {
    casper.echo("TESTS COMPLETED", "GREEN_BAR");
    casper.exit();
  });
});


var partial = function(func /*, 0..n args */) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function() {
    var allArguments = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    return func.apply(this, allArguments);
  };
};
```

The above code is capturing the screen shot for a site developed using meteor. But if I change the url to a site developed using ExtJs, casperjs only produce screenshot which is black. it does not capture the actual screen.

Both the sites are internal sites.  The site developed using ExtJs (not working) uses windows authentication.

What options do I have now?

**After registering various events, I am getting following error:**

```
ResourceError: {
    "errorCode": 5,
    "errorString": "Operation canceled",
    "id": 0,
    "url": "http://cng20018241:9090/"
}
```

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am using phantomjs 1.9.2 version. Let me register to these events to find more.

Comment: @ArtjomB. :  I have updated the question. I am getting resource error. The error code is 5 which means `the operation was canceled via calls to abort() or close() before it was finished.`. Does this mean operation was cancelled by casperjs or the site I am trying to access ?

Comment: Is there some kind of redirect to https? I would suggest upgrading to at least PhantomJS 1.9.7 (or 1.9.8/2.0.0). Then you can try running your script with some additional commanline options: `--ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false`. If it works, remove some of the switches to see what the minimal set is.